# Can I reference an existing patent that was made in 1974? If so, how in depth?

Tags: copyright, infringing, reference, infringe

I have an idea that includes a 'click' spring retractable system (In reference to 'click' pen invention) that was published in 1974. The mechanism would be vastly similar.

How intricately do I have to describe my invention, in accordance to the referenced patent? Am I infringing on any copyrights if I use similar wording or diagrams to the referenced patent? I am looking to submit a provisional application.